# Magento2 How to get configurable option and its price?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, price

I am trying to pull configurable products option and price on product detail page on seprate section. on radio button. I've used below code to get detail of options but i can retrive price of options.

```
$blockObj = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable');


$_attributes = $blockObj->decorateArray($blockObj->getAllowAttributes());

 foreach ($_attributes as $_attribute): ?>

    <?php foreach ($_attribute->getData('options') as $option):    ?>
        // option detail here
     <?php endforeach; ?>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

I've also try to get product id of options but i can get in above data. anyone have idea. how to get it?
Note: I've used objectmanager for testing now. I'll use class to use once my code will be ready

Comment: Prices are associated with the child products of a configurable product, not options. You should just get the prices of the child products.

Comment: @subroutines But there will be some way to get child product id from option id. right? I didn't find it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This code tested on Magento 2.1.4.

All you need is in `getConfigurableOptions` call.

`67` - is a test product ID. In my installation that is a configurable product id. Change it to your product id.

Copy paste it to `testfile.php` and run `php config.php` inside magento root:

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$repository = $obj->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository');
$product = $repository->getById('67');

$data = $product->getTypeInstance()->getConfigurableOptions($product);

$options = array();

foreach($data as $attr){
  foreach($attr as $p){
    $options[$p['sku']][$p['attribute_code']] = $p['option_title'];
  }
}


foreach($options as $sku =>$d){
  $pr = $repository->get($sku);
  foreach($d as $k => $v)
    echo $k.' - '.$v.' ';
  echo ' : '.$pr->getPrice()."\n";
}
```

Here is the output:
[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thanks man. Just once correction use `php testfile.php` instead of `php config.php`

Comment: alright did I earn the bounty?

Comment: Ofcourse. sorry forgot to award bounty.

Comment: Please Update same code for Magento 2

Comment: @KonstantinGerasimov, How to display that info like in the category list page?

Answer (score 3):

Please try below code to get child product object.

```
 $_children = $_product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($_product);
    foreach ($_children as $child){
        $logger->info("Here are your child Product Ids ".$child->getID());
    }
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks. but i want to show price with option. not only child product of configrable product. How can i get relation of option and child product?

Answer (score 0):

What if, not evenn tested but think should work, inject \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository, load some **product** with method: getById

```
    $result = [];
    $options = (array)$product->getOptions();
    foreach ($options as $option) {
        $optionValues = $option->getValues() ? $option->getValues() : [];
        $optionValuesArray = [];
        foreach ($optionValues as $optionValue) {
            $optionValuesArray[] =  [
                'option_id'  => $optionValue->getOptionTypeId(),
                'sku'                 => $optionValue->getSku(),
                'title'           => $optionValue->getTitle(),
                'price'           => $optionValue->getPrice(),
                'price_type'      => $optionValue->getPriceType()
            ];
        }

        $resultOption = [
                    'option_id'  => $option->getOptionId(),
                    'title'      => $option->getTitle(), 
                    'type'       => $option->getType(),
                    'price'      => $option->getPrice(),
                    'price_type' => $option->getPriceType(),
                    'require' => $option->getIsRequire(),
                    'values' => $optionValuesArray
                ]

        $result[] = $resultOption;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the configurable option along with their price all you need to do is,

```
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);
if(!empty($product->getOptions()))
{
foreach($product->getOptions() as $o) {
                foreach ($o->getValues() as $value) {
                    $data=$value->getData();
$id=$data['option_type_id'];
$price=$data['price'];
$title=$data['title'];
}
}
}
```

I have used objectManager though it is not the recommended way to do it.
Just use this code for reference.You can do this by dependency injection.
Hope it helps someone.