# Configurable product in Magento2

Tags: configurable-product, magento2.2, php-7

How to get **product id** if choose option **color** in configure product?

If anyone knows please help me?

Comment: you are asking child product id right?

Comment: Yes ...........

Comment: any idea how to get this id

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/172543/magento2-how-to-get-configurable-option-and-its-price  but i need to provide more in detail

Comment: but how to get selected particular child product id

Comment: how to use this in magento2

Comment: how to get respective child product id if i choose color in config product drop down

Comment: In frontend, you choose config product color pick. you need selected product id. am i correct.

Comment: its clear...........